# Ask a question and notify users on specific users list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications

I thought It could be useful to create a specific user lists to notify them of a created answer.

I thought the lists could be useful for example if you ask an SQL question and you like to notify users are used to SQL problems.

Sometimes I'd like to ask specific questions to specific users because I like their approach or for any other reason. Maybe they could accept or ignore the list request (also automatically).

What do you think?

Comment: This is a very good question for clarification, why people keep downvoting it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

People answer questions on Stack Exchange because they *want* to, not because they *have* to.

Implementing this would change the relationship users have with Stack Exchange for the worse.

As it is the people you want to see your question probably already have the [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) tag marked as "interesting" so they'll be more likely to see the question on the "interesting" tab or they'll be actively searching for SQL questions to answer anyway.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've missed the base concept of Stack Exchange.