# Point another user at a question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ask a question and notify users on specific users list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71727/ask-a-question-and-notify-users-on-specific-users-list)
>   [Route a question to certain user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101894/route-a-question-to-certain-user)

I know we have discussed not having messaging between users because this isn't supposed to be son of facebook.  But is there a place for a way to highlight a particular question to a user?

I saw a new question that I can't answer, but I know it's in the expertise of another user - should there be a way of flagging this to him/her?

Answering questions on here you get to know a group of other users that answer similar question and give quality answers. At the moment there is no contact other than commenting on each others answers - or going offline to their linkedin/facebook page.

Obviously there is a risk of spamming, but inside a group/network of agreeing users this might be useful.

Comment: No matter how useful I feel this might be in some situations, the downsides outweigh it. Perhaps if they participate in a chat you can point them at it there? But that's as "social" as I would get.

Answer (score 8):

One of the important considerations with any feature is, "Does it scale?" This feature would cause problems for the high rep users. Imagine Jon Skeet's inbox for those requests.

I think an important part of SO's design is how users access it as much or as little as they want. Allowing users to poke others would cause a lot of scalability problems, in my opinion.

Comment: +1 I also think "a network of agreeing users" means that at some point it's going to be like Facebook - I have to face the choice of either agreeing to be responsive to someone's chatter, or alienating them when I turn down their request. No sir, I don't like it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - good point, I don't facebook and hadn't thought of that